# Print quality of Kossel clone for Print in Place models

Tags: print-quality, delta, kossel

My first printer is Delta style Kossel clone and I have bad luck with Print In Place (PIP) models, especially with hinges. I suspect that my printer just can't achieve low enough tolerances to make the hinges work.

Are there any tricks I can employ to get better prints for PIP models?

Comment: Much better. Would you share some specs about your printer? like nozzle size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delta printers are considered to be able to be accurate printers cause of the limited weight in the head (using Bowden extruder setup). The positioning can be very accurate (limited weight, limited overshooting) and because of the limited amount of weight, the print speed can be increased.

An [interesting paper](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/mr/v20s2/1516-1439-mr-1980-5373-MR-2016-1039.pdf) has been written on a comparative study between a Cartesian and a Delta machine. The paper concludes that the Delta style printer produces "a better surface finish". However, I'm a bit skeptical as the images of the Cartesian printed part they have printed are of far less quality I can produce with 2 of my printers. Fact is that Delta machines have no Z-wobble (also called [banding](http://www.soliwiki.com/Banding)) that is a common problem with Prusa i3 style printers for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your printer is over-extruding, and this will certainly give less satisfactory results when you try to print models which have internal clearances.

It is also possible that you have some calibration issues which affect orthogonality, x/y/z dimensions or flatness in each axis.

In terms of general improvements, slower and maybe cooler might help - but before jumping in with difficult models, how are your 'standard' print test parts coming out?

Comment: Which 'standard test parts" would you suggest?

Comment: @linuxdan ask that as a separate question...

Comment: asked here https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6470/10422