# What causes inconsistency of sizes?

Tags: print-quality, underextrusion, monoprice-select-mini, dimensional-accuracy

I printed this hook that must have 2.8 mm thickness of all walls:

[image: 3D model with dimensions]

But actual sizes differs:

[image: 3D printed model of a hook with measurements notated]

And I think this is a reason why the 3.0 mm wall has a gap.

Printed with Monoprice Select Mini v2, nozzle 0.4 mm, PLA at 210 °C, PrusaSlicer.

This issue isn't a casual fault, I printed the model several times and always have exactly the same issue.

What causes this inconsistency of sizes?

**UPDATE.** Thanks to Oscar's comment:

> It is a budget cantilever printer, try if orientation of the part makes a difference. E.g. rotate the object 45 or -45° on the build plate by re-slicing.

Indeed, after rotating the model 45° I've get almost perfect print with almost perfect sizes of all walls.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe this is because of non-ideality of printer's mechanics and lots of paths parallel to X or Y axis in the model. For example, when the printer prints a path parallel to X, then Y axis is fixed. Then, to print an adjacent path, Y moved a little (= extrusion width), and because of non-ideality of Y mechanics, there's some error here. By placing the model such way that minimizes the paths when X or Y axis is fixed, it eliminates such defects by averaging the error.

Comment: How dimensionally accurate is your printer? Have you calibrated your 3D printer? How long ago? If you need more info see [What prints can I do to test/calibrate my printer for precision?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6470/what-prints-can-i-do-to-test-calibrate-my-printer-for-precision/6478#6478)

Comment: @agarza: I never calibrate it, but you can see that some sizes are exactly the same as in the model, but some other differs. I think all sizes would changed if the problem was in the calibration.

Comment: Calibration for one axis will not automatically calibrate another. I do find it interesting that both of the horizontal members are different sizes; the same as the vertical ones.

Comment: It is a budget cantilever printer, try if orientation of the part makes a difference. E.g. rotate the object 45 or -45° on the build plate by re-slicing.

Comment: Slop in the relevant belt looks like the most plausible cause.